# Retriving five responses for each comment using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to loop through my MySQL database and retrieve five responses for each comment. The output should be as following

1. First comment

   - First response
   - Second response
   - ...
   - Fifth Response
2. Second comment

   - First response
   - Second response
   - ...
   - Fifth response
3. ...

in order to achieve the above, I'm using the following SQL statement and PHP snippet

```
$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT c.id, c.user_update, r.id reply_id, r.response,
    FROM comments AS c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM responses LIMIT 5) AS r ON (r.reply_id = c.id)
");

try {
    $query->execute();              
    $comments = array();
    $comments_replies = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $comm_id = $row['id'];
        $comments[$comm_id] = $row;
        $comments_replies[$comm_id][] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($comments as $comm_id => $row) {
        echo "<b>".$row['comment']."</b></br></br>";
        foreach ($comments_replies[$comm_id] as $reply_id => $row) {    
            echo $row['response']."</br></br>";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

but it doesn't work so I'm trying to find out what should I change to make it work - to retrieve five responses for each comment and output them as shown above.

Comment: So this hasn't really got anything to do with PHP?

Comment: This is wrong at so many levels... What´s the error? Have you even tried to debug? Have you noticed your query does not even compile?

Comment: provide more details like table structure.

Comment: you don't even have a table alias `m` ... ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table structure

```
+----------------+           +-------------------+
| comments       |           | responses         |
+----------------+           +-------------------+
| id      (int)  | [PK] --|  | id         (int)  | [PK]
| comment (text) |        |--| comment_id (int)  | [FK]     
+----------------+           | response   (text) |   
                             +-------------------+
```

`SQL Statement` - Select five responses for each comment

```
SET @num := 0, @group := '';
SELECT id, comment_id, response
FROM (SELECT id, comment_id, response,
       @num := IF(@group = comment_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row,
       @group := comment_id AS dummy
  FROM responses
  ORDER BY id, comment_id) AS x
WHERE row <= 5
```

If you want only the last five, here's the modified statement

```
SET @num := 0, @group := '';
SELECT id, comment_id, response
FROM (SELECT id, comment_id, response,
       @num := IF(@group = comment_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row,
       @group := comment_id AS dummy
  FROM responses
  ORDER BY id DESC, comment_id) AS x
WHERE row <= 5
```

---

```
// Basic PHP implementation of the SQL statement above

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');

try{
    $db->query("SET @num := 0, @group := '';");
    $query = "
        SELECT comment_id, comment, id, response
        FROM (SELECT r.comment_id, c.comment, r.id, r.response,
                @num := IF(@group = r.comment_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row,
                @group := r.comment_id AS dummy
            FROM responses AS r
            JOIN comments AS c ON c.id = r.comment_id
            ORDER by r.id, r.comment_id) as x
        WHERE row <= 5
    ";

    $current_comment = 0;
    foreach($db->query($query) as $row) {
        if($row['comment_id'] != $current_comment){
            echo '<b>' . $row['id'] .' '. $row['comment'] . '</b><br />';
            $current_comment = $row['comment_id'];
        }
        echo $row['id'] .' '. $row['response'] . "<br />";
    }

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "An Error occured!";
}
```

Check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe2b/51)

Comment: first of all thanks for your help why cant i display the comments
    `try {
    $query->execute();
    $comments = array();
    $comments_replies = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $comm_id = $row['id'];
    $comments[$comm_id]=$row;
    $comments_replies[$comm_id][]=$row;
    }
    foreach ($comments as $comm_id => $row){
    echo "<b>".$row['comments']."</b>";
    foreach ($comments_replies[$comm_id] as $reply_id => $row){
    echo $row['response'];
    }
    }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
    }`

Comment: @Benjamin Well, you asked for an SQL statement which would fetch 5 (last) responses for each comment and I did it ;) have you checked the provided working SQL Fiddle? OK, I could check this snippet in the meantime but you have to know that this code is a PHP snippet and has nothing to do with MySQL or your original question :) And, why you have even three loops...?

Comment: your absolutely right and I'm sorry about the confusion...your query does return what i need but i just dont know how to add it to the code i was working on...also im not sure why im using three loops..... if you can, can you provide a clean and proper way to achieve this :) and yes i did check it on SQL fiddle

Comment: @Benjamin Have you solved the problem? If not, which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Benjamin Here we are, again :) Check the updated answer (the PHP implementation part) and consider accepting it if you find it useful.

Comment: hey @hex494D49 how can i modify the script you provided above to limit how many comments are displayed? im going to write a loadmore script with jquery ajax so i need to limit how many comments are displayed on the page. Once again thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Benjamin change this `WHERE row <= 5` to whatever value you need

Comment: changing the value will only limit the responses I want to know how can I limit the comments I want to display 10 comments with 5 responses to each comment. Thanks